# "Rise up" into the sky

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> "*When we are done, we **rise up into the sky** and become a star...*" ([**Source**](http://www.conceptionhealth.com.au/blog/when-we-are-donewe-rise-up-into-the-sky-and-become-a-star))

I accidentally came across this website and bumped into "**rise up**". I would like to know if it's a superfluous usage or some usage I'm not aware of?

The idea of "**up**" is already contained in the verb "**rise**", which means moving something to a higher level and "**rise**" means "**to move upwards; ascend**". What difference is there between "**rise up**" and "**rise**"?

Comment: It's an idiom ("phrasal verb") that means the same thing as *rise*. In that aspect, it would be superfluous, but not uncommon or unidiomatic to use *up* with it. But I don't see why you couldn't look this up on your own, because the definition is easily accessible online.

Comment: @userr2684291 Nope, neither https://www.google.ru/search?q=rise+up&oq=rise+up&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.1143j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 nor https://www.google.ru/search?q=rise+up&oq=rise+up&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.1143j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22rise+up%22 give information

Comment: My apologies. I falsely assumed you'd taken an *Advanced Googling Techniques & Strats* course at university. Try entering the following search strings into a search engine (one at a time): `rise up meaning` or `rise up definition`. Note that *online* doesn't mean you have to bing or duckduckgo it – you can look it up directly using a built-in search function on certain dictionary websites.

Comment: [This answer by StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/115530/3395) helps identify the distinction between such seemingly equivalent words in their real-world usage.

Comment: @userr2684291 Well, what you have given, I already know. The cases when **rise up** and **rise** are interchangeable are of interest to me. I'm curious at why "**we rise up into the sky**" and not "**we rise into the sky**" is used. So far, userr2684291, you aren't of much help, yet, thank you.

Comment: English is a Germanic language (with later strong French influence). Compare German ***auf**steigen*, to rise/climb/mount up, to ascend. Particles like **up** (auf) can detach and in the case of English have detached and have remained detached from the verb.

Comment: @SovereignSun You know what they say, *you can lead a horse to water...*

Comment: But you cannot make it drink up.

Comment: I can't understand why I have down-votes. It may be a silly question, maybe. However, I often meet phrases like "**raise up your hand**" instead of "**raise your hand**" where "**up**" is superfluous. The idea of **up** is already contained in **raise**, which means moving something to a higher level.

Comment: Not my downvote. But these particles (like **up**) are not superfluous, nor are they idioms. They have been a core feature of Germanic verbs for about 2000 years.

Comment: My knowledge of English isn't that poor. I understand that it's an pleonasm. It's uncertain, however, whether it's used for emphasis or it carries a different meaning that I couldn't feel.

Comment: It's not pleonasm.   "þa ahof paulus up his heafod" [then lifted Paul up his head]. *Then Paul lifted his head up*. You can think of the lifting as a process; **up** conveys the idea that the process continued until the head was in "up" position.  The same with **drink up**.  It means to *finish* the drink, not merely to drink.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Wait a sec... "**drink up**" means "**drink to the last drop**" like in the song by Peter Gabriel - Here comes the flood - **Drink up, dreamers, you're running dry.** It's a phrasal verb actually.

Comment: Are you asking me or telling me? These phenomena are not unrelated.  **Raise up** is a phrasal verb.   *raise up it (ungrammatical).  raise it up (grammatical).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'm discussing it with you. Definitions of "**lift up**" almost everywhere say that it's "**same as lift**". So do definitions of "**rise up**"

Comment: I don't really pay much attention to "definitions everywhere". I studied this stuff in grad school for five years.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Could you provide an answer explaining the difference if any exists, and the usage too? I would love it if you did.

Comment: If you want to do further reading, you can look for articles that discuss the changes over time with "particle-verbs" in English.   Suffice to say that these particles are not mere coprolites in the midden heap of English.

Answer (score 2):

Words like *up*, *out*, *away* are sometimes used with verbs of motion in a redundant manner (e.g. *rise*, *rise up*, *fall*, *fall down*, etc.) to indicate that the motion is significant, far, or over a significant/far distance.  It's a form of emphasis.