# The conjugations of two words change completely the meaning of them

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Exist a phenomenon regarding when two words I know the definition when are conjugated means something utterly different, does exist a code that I do not understand native English speakers use to understand word conjugations like ***"given over"*** in this context?

[image]

I know what means **given** and **over** but the combination of the two doesn't click in my head until I search the definition.

Give = grant the right to someone to possess something and have it

Over = at the top

Give over =  to set apart for a particular purpose or use

Do I really need to remember each meaning conjugation?

Comment: [*Over*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over) has ***far*** more senses than you've indicated in the question. One sense that's relevant here is "**1 f**: from one person or side to another // hand it over." ([*Give*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give) also has many more senses than you've indicated.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford so is lack of vocabulary? That's why I can not understand the meaning of **given over**?

Comment: Lots of learners have this problem. I believe this is related/relevant: [Fall vs Fall down](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115522/fall-vs-fall-down/115530).

Comment: @PabloRamosEscalona Note, too, that there isn't only a single sense of [*give over*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give%20over): (1) *I **gave over** my keys for safe keeping.* (2) *I **gave** myself **over** to the Dark Side.* (3) "***Give over***, *guv! Stop pulling my leg.*"

Comment: As a side note, *conjugation* in English refers to the inflection of a verb reflecting its tense, number, and other functions, e.g. *give, gave, given* or *remember, remembered, remembered*. An occurrence of a word with another word is a *collocation*, but there is no specific term for the change in meaning when a verb is collocated with certain prepositions; these are simply *verb-preposition pairs* or *verb-preposition combinations* or the like.

Answer (score 2):

English has many [phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb), consisting of a verb plus a preposition or adverb.

While there are some patterns to them (for example, many phrasal verbs containing *up* have a sense of completing something) generally they need to be learnt individually. A good dictionary will list them.

So, the answer is, Yes, you do need to learn them.

Note that *give over* in the sense of "devote" is rare in the active: it is nearly always in the passive *given over*.

Note also that *Exist a phenomenon* is not English. The English for that is *Does there exist a phenomenon*, or *Does a phenomenon exist*, or, most likely, *Is there a phenomenon*.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite as bad as you think. Only **some** conjunctions of verb and preposition have a meaning distinct from the meanings of the words separately. But those specific combinations you must learn; there is no code.