# Yank something vs Yank at something

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

1. John yanked at the arm.
2. John yanked the arm.

I am confused about the meaning of these sentences. What’s the difference between them?

Comment: Related reading: [Fall vs Fall down](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115522/fall-vs-fall-down).

Comment: @Em Please explain my problem. As a foreign English learner, it’s difficult sometimes to understand some particular things.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference. In both cases, the reader determines that John used his hand to pull, probably with speed and some force, at the 'arm', whatever that is. Using "at" bears a slight implication that the pull did not bring the arm as far as he had meant it to go, in other words, that John was slightly unsuccessful at pulling it where he intended. But that implication is slight, and might not have been what the speaker or writer meant.